# render multiple frames using a for loop, stack overflow after one image. Is there anyway to avoid stacking while rendering?

Tags: python

I am trying to move the camera around an interested object, and then render frames along the camera trajectory. The trajectory part worked well, but when I tried to render frames and save the depth map from a node (see the attached code), I have overstack issue. Is there anyway to solve the problem?

PS: I am a newbie in Blender, so I don't even know if I did it completely wrong in the very beginning. Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

```
SCENE_NAME='123'
viewCount = 0
stepSize=12
scene = bpy.context.scene
stickGroup = list(i for i in bpy.data.objects if 'stick' in i.name)
camera = scene.objects['Camera']

def getPath():
   myPath = savePathConfigure();
   myPath.gtSaveDIR = 
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath), 'Dataset/'+SCENE_NAME+'/')
   myPath.outRGBpath = os.path.join(myPath.gtSaveDIR, 'RGB/')
   myPath.outDepPath = os.path.join(myPath.gtSaveDIR, 'Depth/')

   if myPath.pathConfig()=={'FINISHED'}:
      print(myPath.gtSaveDIR)

   return myPath

class getRGBHandler:
   def __init__(self, path_in):
      self.base_path = path_in

   @persistent
   def __call__(self, scene):
      bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['File Output'].base_path = self.base_path
      bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)



class getDepthHandler:
   def __init__(self, path_in):
      self.base_path = path_in

   @persistent
   def __call__(self, scene):
      pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
      np.save(os.path.join(self.base_path, str(viewCount)+'.npy'), pixels)

def moveCamHandler(scene):
   cameraOrigin = camera.location
   newTheta = stepSize* (math.pi/180)  # rotate the camera completely around the focused point
   # This rotating is in global coordinate system
   rotationMatrix =np.array([  [math.cos(newTheta), -math.sin(newTheta), 0.],\
                            [math.sin(newTheta), math.cos(newTheta), 0.],\
                            [0., 0., 1.]  ])
   goal = Vector(np.dot(cameraOrigin, rotationMatrix))
   gaze = Vector(np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.double))  # look at the origin
   camera.location = goal

   gazeRay = gaze - camera.location
   camEulerAng = gazeRay.to_track_quat('-Z', 'Y').to_euler()
   camera.rotation_euler = camEulerAng

def callMyHandlers():
   saveDIR =getPath()
   myGT = groundTruthStruct(whatScene= SCENE_NAME, objectGroup = stickGroup)

   bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()     
   bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(getRGBHandler(saveDIR.outRGBpath))   
   bpy.app.handlers.render_post.append(getDepthHandler(saveDIR.outDepPath))


# Main loop
callMyHandlers()

for i in range(30):
   scene.frame_set(i*stepSize+1)
   viewCount+=1
   scn.render.filepath = '/outputDIR/'+str(viewCount)+'.png'
   bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True,use_viewport=True)
   scene.update()
```

I have a node tree like this (see image), what I want is the depth value. Directly adding a **File Out Node** will lose some accuracy (double -> int16). 
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, I have not verified this since I am not able to run  the code myself without the objects referred from it.

The `frame_change_pre` handler is the method `getRGBHandler.__call__`, which is making a call to `bpy.ops.render.render`. The render call, however, in its turn calls frame_change_pre handler triggering a call to `getRGBHandler.__call__`, which again calls render. This is causing an infinite recursion, resulting in stack overflow.

It may not be a good idea to call render from within the `frame_change_pre` handler. You might want to try and move it to the main code. I didn't quite get the logic, so I am unable to suggest where it should be. But am tempted to observe: main is already calling render, is there a need for another render in the handler?

Lastly, (in case you are unaware of this) there's an easier way to get the rotation matrix, namely:
`mathutils.Euler([0, 0, newTheta], 'XYZ').to_matrix()`. And 
newTheta can be caluclated only once, since it depends solely on stepSize (math.radians(stepSize))? mathutils.Vector has methods for dot and cross products.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works smoothly after I moved all the render commands in the main loop and delete repeated one. It turns out I was trapped in those handlers, which caused me a lot of troubles. Appreciate again.

Comment: You are welcome :) Glad that I could be of help.